# Server-side auth and request timeouts to Facebook?

Tags: facebook, authentication, oauth

Part of my app requires login and is not able to use client-side authentication with javascript etc, so requests authentication server-side using http request on:

`https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=[app_id]&client_secret=[secret]&redirect_uri=[uri]&code=[code]`

This works fine, most of the time. However I intermittently get timeout/null responses back from this request. I can run a tool which will request this page over and over, and will succeed about 80-90% of the time. As soon as one failure occurs, all requests fail, for any user, for a few seconds and then it works again.

Has anyone else experienced something like this, or do you know if there is a cap on requests which facebook will cut off over a certain threshold? I can't find any information that sounds similar in the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because if you send too much requests, facebook thinks you want to make a DDOS attack and block your requests for a while.

Comment: I considered that previously but I am making no where near enough requests for that surely? The app has about 100k users and only 30-40k api requests a day on my insights.

Comment: If that _was_ the case, then you should find information about it in your app insights, on the "API" tab.

Answer (score 1):

You must retreive the token only once for your session. Other way it certainly turning FB defending against throtting.
However, if you're not apply for 'offline_access' special permission, your token has expiration time.
Default is retentionPeriod=2 and retentionUnit=hour.
maybe you should ask for

```
scope=offline_access
```

into your permission, then only retreive the user token once. 
In addition you need to perform a

```
try{my api call} catch(bad token){ reload the new token and retry }
```

which is re-ask the token if any API call failed with authenticaion error.

Comment: I think using offline_access to get past this problem is overkill, but I do agree that caching the tokens to try and ensure it is only being requested once is a good idea. However if you are trying to sign the user in, you cant use a cached token because obviously you want to check that the user has actually signed in, not just that you have their access token stored

Comment: well, in OAuth 2.0,  the fb cookies is setting up for this purpose.

Comment: @Guillaume-Pelletier Does the cookie get around [Abby](http://stackoverflow.com/users/911412/abby)'s concern that you cannot use a cached token just in case they are not really logged in?

Comment: Cached Token is a server side concern.. not the same scenario. For instance it is like you're using any application, even from a 'non trusted' device and want the application (like deezer) post update on your wall or timeline.

Comment: @GuillaumePelletier I'm still confused, when you say "You must retreive the token only once for your session" where's that stated in the FB API docs? I'll try and formulate my issue as a detailed question and reference this discussion.

Answer (score 0):

In app Insights, you can check API throtting from diagnostics page, and also most common errors from performance page. If you don't see any error or nothing been throttled, you could probably change the app logic, request the token again if you get timeout/null responses.

Comment: no throttling on my diagnostics, nor errors. I have implemented a retry but some of them are having to retry up to 20-30 times before succeeding.